# Jquery, Add Remove class

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a class and remove the class from a input tag.

```
$("#idNumber").addClass("numbers")
```

and

```
$('#idNumber').removeAttr('class'); 
$("#idNumber").removeClass("numbers")
```

When I remove the class, my html looks as follow:

```
<input id="idNumber" type="text" placeholder="ID Number..." data-bind="value: IdNumber" onkeyup="valSAID();">
```

When I add the class it looks like follow:

```
<input id="idNumber" type="text" placeholder="ID Number..." data-bind="value: IdNumber" onkeyup="valSAID();" maxlength="13" class="numbers">
```

The problem I have is that the class effect is still applied on this input tag.

Please help

Comment: Take a look at your CSS file and see if there are any styles that effect <input> or "#idNumber"

Comment: try to remove the class only using the removeClass-Method. skip the removeAttr-Method

Comment: also it would be nice if you can tell us in which browser this is happening

Comment: Which class effect are you talking about?

Comment: There are no other classes that affect the <input> or "idNumber", I have tried calling only remove class. It does the same.

Comment: You don't need both removeAtrr and removeClass - if you use the removeAttr, the class attribute won't exist so calling remove class after it is not going to do anything.  Also you may want to chain the events in future for better performance.  Please add your css to the question too

Comment: This happens in all four of my browsers, Chrome, Firefox, IE, Maxthon

Comment: Ok but what do you call a "class effect"? A CSS rule, an event handler or what??? And if you post relevant code, it'd be a clever move